# Show that a linear system has at least one solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I would like your help to show that the system below has  at least one solution.

Let $\mathcal{Y}\equiv \{0,1\}$. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a finite set containing positive and negative numbers.

Consider the system of equations below. The vector of unknowns is $(x_{y,v}: y\in \mathcal{Y}, v\in \mathcal{V})$. The vectors $(w_v: v\in \mathcal{V})$ and $(q_y: y\in \mathcal{Y})$ and the sets $\mathcal{V},\mathcal{Y}$ are known.
$$
(*) \quad \begin{cases}
&(1) \quad \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}x_{y,v} =w_v \quad \forall v \in \mathcal{V},\\
&(2) \quad \sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} x_{y,v}=q_y\quad \forall y\in \mathcal{Y},\\
& -----------------------\\
&(3) \quad\sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} x_{1,v} *v \geq 0,\\
&(4) \quad\sum_{v\in \mathcal{V}} x_{0,v} *v \leq  0,\\
&--------------------\\
&(5) \quad \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y},v\in \mathcal{V}} x_{y,v}=1,\\
&(6) \quad 0\leq x_{y,v}\leq 1 \quad \forall y\in \mathcal{Y}, v\in \mathcal{V},\\
&(7) \quad \sum_{v\in \mathcal{V} } w_v=1,\\
&(8) \quad 0\leq w_v\leq 1 \quad \forall  v\in \mathcal{V},\\
&(9) \quad \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y} } q_y=1,\\
&(10) \quad 0\leq q_y\leq 1 \quad \forall  y\in \mathcal{Y}.\\
\end{cases}
$$

**Question**: Show that $(*)$ has at least one solution.

**Note**: The claim seems to me correct. For example, let $\mathcal{V}\equiv \{-1,1\}$. The system $(*)$ reduces to
$$
\begin{cases}
(a)\quad x_{0,1}+x_{1,1}=w_1,\\
(b)\quad x_{0,-1}+x_{1,-1}=1-w_1,\\
(c)\quad x_{0,1}+x_{0,-1}=q_0,\\
(d)\quad x_{1,1}+x_{1,-1}=1-q_0,\\
(e)\quad x_{1,1}-x_{1,-1}\geq 0,\\
(f)\quad x_{0,1}-x_{0,-1}\leq 0,
\end{cases}
$$
which I think has many solutions. I would like to show the claim in a general way.

Comment: from what I see, (7) and (9) are redundant because (1) (2) and (5) together give them. Everything else I would just characterize as row-sums and column-sums together with dot product are known. As far as showing a solution, I think a bounded sub-space argument could be made, is that what you might be looiking for?

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for an expert advice. I'm not very skilled in linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{V}\equiv \{-1,1\}$ and $q_1 = 1/10 = w_{-1}$, $q_0=9/10 = w_{1}$. In this case the problem has no solution since (4) cannot hold:
$$
x_{0,1} - x_{0,-1} =  q_0 - 2 x_{0,-1} \ge q_0 - 2 w_{-1} = 7/10 >0
$$

Comment: Thanks. Looking at my example, the first step comes from (c): $x_{0,1}+x_{0,-1}-2 x_{0,-1}=q_0-2 x_{0,-1}$ which becomes $x_{0,1}-x_{0,-1}=q_0-2 x_{0,-1}$.  I don't understand where the next inequality comes from, could you add more details? From (b), $x_{0,-1}=w_{-1}-x_{1,-1}$. Hence, $q_0-2 x_{0,-1}=q_0-2 w_{-1}-2 x_{1,-1}$ and, so, $q_0-2 x_{0,-1}\leq q_0-2 w_{-1}$.

Comment: @TEX you have a wrong sign in your derivation. $x_{0,-1}=w_{-1}-x_{1,-1}\implies q_0-2 x_{0,-1}=q_0-2 w_{-1} \color{red}{+} 2 x_{1,-1}$